# Wpf Docking Control with UI Automation compatibility

Tags: wpf, telerik, ui-automation, docking, ranorex

We have slowly been creating UI Automation tests using Ranorex on our product but have ran into several problems.

We are using Telerik Wpf controls (TabControl, TreeView, Grid and Docking) and so far we've only been able to test the TreeView and Grid using Ranorex. We replaced the TabControl for the standard Wpf TabControl which works with Ranorex. However the Docking control does not work and of course there is no standard out of the box Wpf Docking control for us to use instead.

My question is this: Does anybody know of any Wpf Docking controls that can be tested using an UI Automation tool (preferably Ranorex)?

I found [AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/), which at first looked promising, but according to [this](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=219728) thread on their site it doesn't support UI Automation :(

Cheers for any comments,

Siy

Comment: Yup, that's what I was afraid of; bugger all controls.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Telerik has their own product that supports UI automation for WPF -  [Telerik Test Studio](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/wpf-testing.aspx) - including [RadDocking](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/docking.aspx) control.

Comment: Thanks for the link I'll have a look and see what it offers. I doubt my bosses will want to jump into bed with another Telerik product after all the issues we've had though.